# API to get artifacts created in last 24 Hrs

Tags: artifactory, artifact, jfrog-cli

I know JFrog provides APIs to fetch the artifacts info like latest build etc. 
Can some one help by telling if JFrog provides an API to fetch the artifacts created/promoted in last 24 hr / last month etc.

Would like to pull all the artifacts updated in last one month for audit purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality using AQL (Artifactory Query Language) and JFrog CLI.

1. Build an AQL query using [RelativeTimeOperators](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-RelativeTimeOperators) (`{"$last" : "30d"}` for example).
2. Create a [file spec](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UsingFileSpecs) with the `"aql"` field.
3. Use the [download](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadingFiles) command of the CLI and provide the file spec you created with the `--spec` flag to download the files.

If you'd like to just get a list of artifacts, you can use the [search](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SearchingFiles) command.